# Regular Expression - Get if there is just one

Tags: regex

**I would like a regex which**

Grabs **`target`** from This:

> http://localhost/target or http://localhost/target/

But NOT from This:

> http://localhost/target/something/else

So If there is just one parameter after localhost and not more than one.

Comment: Most languages have url parsing modules either in the standard library or elsewhere. What language are you using?

Comment: @Rafe Kettler there are valid reasons to try and do this with regex, like django urlpatterns

Answer (score 5):

This should get you going:

```
^.*target/?$
```

Comment: @Sarfraz: Why? `/` is not a metacharacter, and who knows if CIRK is using a regex dialect that uses it as a delimiter?

Comment: @Sarfraz: Who said anything about Ruby? Just because you need to escape the slash in Ruby because Ruby happens to use it as a regex delimiter doesn't mean that the regex itself needs it. In Python, .NET, PCRE and many other dialects it is not necessary (and in some considered an error) to escape a slash.

Comment: I don't consider the slash escaping a problem related to _regex_, but to the regex implementation in specific languages, so I keep it like this; if the OP needs to escape it, he will.

Answer (score 0):

```
'http://localhost/target/'.match( /^http:\/\/localhost\/(target)\/?$/ )
```

would match

- http://localhost/target
- http://localhost/target/

And not match

- http://localhost/target/f

You didnt specify whether the http matching was required, but if it isn't just remove that portion. This is a fairly primitive regex but should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^http:\/\/localhost\/([^\/]+)\/?$/
```

Or if you can do a different delimiter like in Perl, to avoid LTS:

```
m|^http://localhost/([^/]+)/?$|
```